# list string to single string

Tags: android, string, list

I have a situation in which I want to convert a `List<String>` to a single `String` and with commas

PS : I'm using RootTools library for command and I wanna execute a

```
Busybox --list command
```

Comment: You could do this by using a `StringBuilder`, iterating through each element of the list and appending it to the builder.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your list and add elements as they come to a String.
This is one way of doing it but there are others.

```
List<String> myList ;
String result = "";
//...
for (String tmp : myList) {
    result += tmp+","
}
```